# CHange php 5.4 to 5.5 on Hostgator

Tags: php, linux, command-line

Currently on composer install I get the error need 5.5.9 but using 5.4 but on Hostgator cpanal it's set as 5.5

On `php -v` I get

```
PHP 5.4.45
```

On `php --ini` I get

```
Configuration file (php.ini) Path: /opt/php54/lib
```

When going into /opt/
There is a php54, php55 and php56

How do I change my version to 5.5

I saw the following example on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206864/use-different-php-version-cli-executable-for-one-command)

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.x (cli) ...
$ set PATH="/usr/lib64/php5.6/bin:$PATH"
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.x (cli) ...
```

But when going into /usr/lib64 there's no php5.6

On my index file in the webserver I did a phpinfo() and it's set as 5.5

Anyone got any ideas

Comment: what about contacting hostgator's support?

Comment: I've already put a ticket in to them but had no luck so far. I thought it would be an easy one for a regular linux user. It's just changing the php destination but I just have no idea how that is done. I just don't want to type in what I think is right because I've had experience in messing things like this up in the past.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On my hostgator shared hosting, the php 5.6 executable is located at  `/opt/php56/bin/php`

You can use `ls /opt` to see if the php version folders exist.

So if you want to update your php command with 5.6 you should edit your `~/.bash_profile` and append the following line:

```
alias php='/opt/php56/bin/php'
```

You might have to logout and log in again if you dont see a change.

Now, when you use `php -v` it should say `5.6.x` if you have done it right.

This works the same with 7.0 and any other php versions should be located in the same dir.

Comment: It works for me in php7.1. I used alias php='/opt/php71/bin/php'