# cakephp 3 installation error with composer

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, wamp, cakephp-3.0

I have Php 7 installed but whenever I try to install CakePHP from the command line using composer I get this error:

Your version of PHP, 5.4.0beta2-dev, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot safely perform certificate validation, we strongly suggest you upgrade.

my PHP version is up to date and I can't install CakePHP locally as it will provide many errors

Comment: what does running 'php -v' from the command line return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read that error message again. It's more than clear:

> Your version of **PHP, 5.4.0beta2-dev**, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot safely perform certificate validation, we strongly suggest you upgrade.

You obviously **don't** run php 7 in your CLI environment.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163762/php-cli-and-bash-change-behaviour-of-php-keyword
- [Use different PHP version CLI executable for one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206864/use-different-php-version-cli-executable-for-one-command)
- [How to access PHP with the Command Line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows)
- [Let me google that for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20change%20path%20variable)